# XAMPP mysql_connect could not connect to host

Tags: mysql, xampp

I recently installed latest version of Xampp on Windows 7, and configured with ports under Apache, that is browsing fine the files and directories. But database connection become failed. I also have confirmed user information, databases etc,but it is showing errors below

> Warning: mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

This is PHP code to connect database

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("database_name")or die(mysql_error());
```

Please guide me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("database_name", $conn)or die(mysql_error());
```

don't forget of your password of db

Comment: Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource

Comment: you need to check your data of Connection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934903/iis-php-mysql-a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-n